# Is the road from Delhi to Nepal Safe?

Tags: buses, driving, nepal, new-delhi, kathmandu

Recently a new bus service was launched from Delhi to Nepal directly. I was just wondering how the roads were?

I remember going to Nepal about 20 years ago, I was very young but do recall staying stuck for hours at a place for the roads to clear and roads being quite dangerous and scary.. Just wondering in case I decide to go..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you see the trend of tourist coming to Nepal by land in 2013. It shows more than 200000 tourist come from land and obviously from India.

There are different route for coming to the border of Nepal, Some people also take train also. There are different entering route from Delhi, some famous are Bhairahawa, Birgunj, Mahendranagar. But connecting point is Narayangarh. Rode upto Narayangarh is better safe and construction is also going for widen up. But rode from Narayangarh-Muglin-Kathmandu looks danger as Tom said above specially in Rainy season.

Answer (score 9):

I imagine the new bus service would follow the Narayanghat Mugling Highway to get into the higher valleys and onto Kathmandu or Pokhara.

Without knowing where you went within Nepal 20 years back, I would hazard a guess that maybe you went up either the Siddharta Highway (to Pokhara) or the Tribhuvan Highway (to Kathmandu).  Both of these roads are still subject to frequent closures due to washouts from monsoon rains and rock slides.

Is it any safer/better today? Rock slides and wash outs can occur even today, as mother nature is stronger than most everything man can build. If you are not traveling during the rainy season, then likely the ride will go through more or less on schedule.  If you need to go during the rainy season be prepared.